# Vue frontend, Rails backend, and Facebook Authentication confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, vue.js, authentication, oauth

**Background**
I have two applications - A frontend in VueJS and a Rails backend.
I have implemented a stateless authentication mechanism using the Knock gem. When a user signs up/in from the frontend, the server sends back a JWT.
Now the frontend sends all requests to the backend with the JWT in an Authentication header in the form `Bearer {JWT}`.
This is fairly simple and straightforward, but I now want to also allow users the ability to login with Facebook.

**Main**
I don’t want users to be redirected off-site if they want to login via FB, so I implemented the FB SDK in my frontend (separate server & url from the backend) which makes a call to Facebook and successfully authenticates them on the facebook side.

… And this is where my main problem is - Where do I go from here?
I’ve thought of three approaches

1. The first approach I tried was to make the request from the frontend and then set Facebook's `signed_request` in a cookie ` and use Omniauth-facebook & Devise to parse the request and from there make another request to FB and get the user data and create the user. I then create the user and send back my own custom JWT token (using Knock) to be used by the frontend. This feels very weird since I’m already using Knock. Do I really need to use Devise here too?
2. Another approach would be to only send Facebook’s access_token to the backend and use Koala to make more calls to FB and then again set my own JWT token which gets returned to the frontend.
3. Make the authentication request from the frontend, then make a second request to facebook to get the user data, send the user data to the backend to create the new user and then create my own JWT token that gets sent back to the frontend - In this scenario, what would my callback URL be? Right now this is on the backend.

My main with all approaches are:
1) Should I be using my own JWT tokens or are FB access token a replacement?
2) Should the callback URLs be on the Frontend or Backend, and are they of any practical use if I’m only using FB for authentication?
3) At what point should and I check if the token has expired and where? Frontend or Backend? If I receive a token that has expired, how should this be handled?
4) I would like to require the user to grant permission to access email. Should this "rejection" be done on the frontend or backend if the user has not allowed the email permission?

**TLDR**
I’m very confused with what flow I should be using when I have a frontend, backend and using facebook authentication alongside my own custom authentication. I’ve read loads online but it only seems to have confused me, since a lot of the resources seem to either only use a single app, only use facebook authentication, or are only Frontend apps using something like Firebase for the backend.

I’m very sorry is this mini-essay is a bit muddled, but it’s probably testimony to how much this has confused me. Is there even a “right” approach, or are there multiple approaches I can take, and they are purely down to personal preference? Any help that could set me in the right direction would be very, very much appreciated!